# Try to execute a script (adduser.sh) in root /$

Tags: scripts

I'm a new user to Linux and been practicing using creating/using scripts in bash.

I found a script to add new users automatically but when I try to run the script in root, I keep getting the same error message :'`No such file or directory`'. the message snippet is as follows:

```
student@Ubuntu1410:/$ chmod +x /home/student/Scripts/adduser.sh
student@Ubuntu1410:/$ ./adduser.sh
bash: ./adduser.sh: No such file or directory
student@Ubuntu1410:/$
```

Comment: Can we see the contents of the script? Where have you saved the script? have you used `cd` to go to that directory?

Answer (score 0):

If your script is in `/home/student/Scripts/` then start it from there.

```
cd /home/student/Scripts
./adduser.sh
```

Or with path

```
sh /home/student/Scripts/adduser.sh
```

I do not know what the script is. It probably will need sudo.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6I navigated to my Scripts directory and then used sudo ./adduser.sh and it worked perfectly

Comment: @shuggs81 Just so you know for the future, there's a way to show your current location in the filesystem next to the [command line prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html).  The dot slash literally means run executable that is in the current working directory. Now, if you also [add that Scripts folder to your $PATH variable](http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/295286), you can run scripts in that folder from anywhere.

Comment: @Pilot6 good job noticing that the user wasn't in the right directory right away  ! +1

Comment: @shuggs81 If the answer solves your problem, the appropriate thing to do is accept the answer. It creates clarity the answer worked for you.